# How to write text box message in visual basic if someone leaves txtFirstName or txtMiddleName or txtLastName Box Empty

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to stackoverflow.  I'm hoping someone may be able to help me in figuring out just what I'm doing wrong.  I'm new to programming and visual basic.  My class is introduction to programming.  So please, if my program is not correctly formatted, I would be glad for some suggestions.  I've ran it and get the results I'm looking for, but I want to add an additional message box.  The message box is to display a message if the txtFirstName or txtMiddleName or txtLastName box is left empty.  I thought if I put:

```
If txtFirstName.Text = "" Then
   MessageBox.Show("Name needed")
```

I get an error message:  Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Like I said, I'm a beginner.  I'm just trying to figure out what it is I'm doing wrong.

```
Private Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
          Handles btnProcess.Click
    'Declare variables

    Dim strFirstName As String = txtFirstName.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()
    Dim strMiddleName As String = txtMiddleName.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()
    Dim strLastName As String = txtLastName.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()
    Dim strId = txtId.Text.Substring(0, 2)


    'Declare  a variable to hold line message
    Dim strMessage As String = ""


    'Use if then elseif to determine which line message
    If strLastName = "A" Or strLastName = "B" Or strLastName = "C" _
        Or strLastName = "D" Or strLastName = "E" Or strLastName = "F" Then
        strMessage = "Line 1."

    ElseIf strLastName = "G" Or strLastName = "H" Or strLastName = "I" _
        Or strLastName = "J" Or strLastName = "K" Or strLastName = "L" Then
        strMessage = "Line 2."

    ElseIf strLastName = "M" Or strLastName = "N" Or strLastName = "O" _
         Or strLastName = "P" Or strLastName = "Q" Then
        strMessage = "Line 3."

    ElseIf strLastName = "R" Or strLastName = "S" Or strLastName = "T" _
        Or strLastName = "U" Or strLastName = "V" Then
        strMessage = "Line 4."

    ElseIf strLastName = "W" Or strLastName = "X" Or strLastName = "Y" _
          Or strLastName = "Z" Then
        strMessage = "Line 5."
    End If

    MessageBox.Show("You are in " & strMessage & " Your pin number is " & strFirstName & strMiddleName & strLastName & strId & ". ")

   End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using If Then Else If to select Last Name based on First Letter then Display a MessageBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467963/using-if-then-else-if-to-select-last-name-based-on-first-letter-then-display-a-m)  We just saw this question a few days ago - this is either a clone/duplicate/replacement/sock puppet account or homework going around

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question (i.e. and not complete the homework assignment!) the reason for your error is that if the text box is blank VB can't process the `Substring` within it.

This line

```
Dim strFirstName As String = txtFirstName.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()
```

could be replaced with

```
Dim strFirstName As String = String.Empty
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text.Trim) Then
    strFirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper
End If
```

This ensures that the variable is initialised to a known value and the contents of the text box are checked before string processing.

I hope you enjoy your time with VB - I've been using it for 18 years and still can't tear myself away to learn C# properly!

Comment: Everything is working when I put in the information, it is just when I try and display a message the textboxes are left blank I get the error.  I tried the above, but still can't get it to work. Thanks for posting.  Hopefully I will figure it out.

Comment: Sigh.  The whole point is that you check the content of the textboxes before doing anything.  Try looking up `String.IsNullOrEmpty` on MSDN.